# Use PC screen on Laptop OBS?

Tags: laptop, video, desktop-computer, webcam

I am trying to set up a live stream on Twitch with a webcam showing stuff. Due to my lack of a professional webcam I used to connect my phone camera to my PC. However, that setup suffers significantly from reduced performance, lag and major failure. So, I started looking for professional cameras.

When I first looked for webcams I found out that most of them are rather cheap and don't do what they are supposed to do.
Next I looked for video cameras, but their functionality is rather inconsistent: Even though most of those cameras do have the technology needed to live stream their image to a connected PC... they won't do it.

After some thinking I got another idea: Experience taught me that laptop cameras usually work fine (enough). So my next idea was to get myself a laptop and feed the image of the built-in camera into OBS on my desktop PC. But then I thought of an even smarter approach (hopefully):

**What if I feed the screen of my PC into the laptop?**

With a VGA splitter I can use my desktop PC monitor as usual **while** feeding the video signal into my laptop for use in OBS. That would also eliminate my performance issues (I have an old setup).

Now I know that Laptop video ports are usually OUT ports. Is it possible to convert the VGA signal into a signal I can input into the laptop? Maybe **VGA to USB** or **VGA to HDMI** (if that's an IN/OUT port)?

If I go with USB, will I have the same issues as with the phone camera (lags, distortions,...)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Video ports are **always** out ports, not just 'usually'. You would need a dedicated capture device. If you can't get a USB webcam to work at full spec, then look to your computer, not the camera.

Comment: But how would the capture device then feed the video signal into a Laptop/Desktop? It's got to use some port.

Comment: Used to be PCIe, but you can get USB these days.